# Return on error in shellscript instead of exit on error

Tags: bash, shell, function

I know that `set -e` is my friend in order to exit on error. But what to do if the script is sourced, e.g. a function is executed from console? I don't want to get the console closed on error, I just want to stop the script and display the error-message.

Do I need to check the $? of each command by hand to make that possible ?

Here an example-script `myScript.sh` to show the problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

copySomeStuff()
{
    source="$1"
    dest="$2"
    cp -rt "$source" "$dest"
    return 0
}

installStuff()
{
    dest="$1"
    copySomeStuff dir1 "$dest"
    copySomeStuff dir2 "$dest"
    copySomeStuff nonExistingDirectory "$dest"
}
```

The script is used like that:

```
$ source myScript.sh
$ installStuff
```

This will just close down the console. The error displayed by `cp` is lost.

Comment: Are you sure it would close down the console? I tried to run the script as you described and it terminates the whole things throwing `cp` error and exiting with 1 exit code.

Comment: @ddnomad The `set -e` sets the `errexit` option in the shell. When calling the function, the `cp` fails and the shell exits for me.

Comment: If you source that it will ignore the `#!` and will apply `set -e ` to the calling shell, so will apply to all subsequent commands.

Comment: Double quote your user input. Don't use `()` when calling shell functions.

Comment: `${dest}` and `${source}` are still unquoted, and they contain user input. I'm being a bit picky with you here, but you need to quote them in your script on your machine, or simple things like copying files with spaces in their names won't work. Sorry. I'm just trying to give constructive feedback.

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine that you are picky here, thanks for the feedback!  Saves my script from failing in some cases which I just did not consider so far !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend having one script that you run as a sub-shell, possibly sourcing a file to read in function definitions. Let that script set the `errexit` shell option for itself.

When you use `source` from the command line, "the script" is effectively your interactive shell.  Exiting means terminating the shell session.  There are possibly ways around this, but the best option, if you wanted to set `errexit` for a session, would be to simply have:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

source file_with_functions
do_things_using_functions
```

Additional benefit: Will not pollute the interactive session with functions.

Comment: Ok, that does the job, thanks! It's a more readable solution and probably should be preferred in most cases. However for my special use-case it would result in 6 files, since I provide different services there, currently implemented as functions, and I would like to stick to 1 file for other reason.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work for me - I'm calling a function defined in my shell-rc file, so I can't reasonably execute it from somewhere else

Answer (score 5):

If you source that, it will ignore the `#!` and will apply `set -e` to the calling shell, so will apply to all subsequent commands.

you could force a sub-shell:

```
copySomeStuff()
{
    (
        set -e
        source="$1"
        dest="$2"
        cp -r "$source" "$dest"
        return 0
    )
}
```

---

Also for safety:

- Do not use all caps variable name, as likely to collide with environment names. (we had a question last week about why a script did not work, it had a variable PATH)
- Use quotes.
- Always use `-t` or `-T` option for `cp`, `mv`, `ln`. e.g.

  - `cp -t destination_directory source_files …`
  - `cp -T source_file destination_file`

  note that `-t` and `-T` are Gnu extensions, and not available on some other Unixes, so for portability you can in place of the `-t` option do:

  - `cp source_files … destination_directory/`

  I do not know of an alternate safe form for `-T`

Comment: Just a note about `cp -t`, it's a GNU extension not available on BSD systems. If GNU `coreutils` is installed, GNU `cp` may be available as `gcp`.

Comment: `set -e` in the sub-shell works great, thanks ! As well thanks for the safety-hints.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it is perfect. It also ensures that `set -e` is not set in the calling `shell`

Comment: subshell works, except that the stdout and stderr of the subshell seem to be lost :/

Comment: @Xerus you will have to ask a new question, showing an example of what you did. Subsshell does not loose stdout or stderr.

Comment: yeah, there was some other weird error going on swallowing my output, found it after debugging a while ^^